# Keras Predictions on python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have this code for my CNN:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K

# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 64, 64

train_data_dir = "path_trainning"
validation_data_dir = "path_validation"
nb_train_samples = 2000
nb_validation_samples = 800
epochs = 10
batch_size = 16

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for training
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

model.save('my_cnn.h5')
```

And this is the code for my predictions:

```
for file in os.listdir(targets_path):
    filef = '\\' + file
    test_image = image.load_img(targets_path + filef, target_size=(64, 64))
    test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
    test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)
    result = model.predict(test_image)
    print("\nOriginal: " + file)
    print("Prediction: " + str(result[0][0]))
    if result[0][0] == 1:
        prediction = 'dog'
    else:
        prediction = 'cat'
    print(prediction)
```

My question is:

With this code as the "Prediction" part, I am realising that unless the CNN has a 1, it won't be a dog. And I am getting results like 0.99999 is a cat, but with that value it is closer to be a dog.

I think I am not understanding it properly.

Could someone explain me please?

Answer (score 0):

That is due to the output layer being a node with sigmoid activation, which returns values between 0 and 1. Therefore, the result will never be 1 (or 0), so that code will always return 'cat'.

Comment: Okey, I edited the post. But also, i get some dogs too. Sometimes it returns 1.0

Comment: Remember, your output is a "probability" of each class, thus if you assign label 1 =cat then having a probability >0.5 for a test image will result in, you should predict it as a cat.

Comment: This is what i dont understand. Me, as a programmer, if an image has >0.5 P of being a dog, i will say it is a dog. But on the code i posted i only have a dog if it is equals to 1. So... Should i change that and put ``if result[0][0] > 0.5`` or something??

Answer (score 0):

This might be the issue with your CNN.

You are using an ReLU activation in the hidden layers. They have an output range from 0 to Infinity. When these values flow through the final output activation which is sigmoid in your case. If I pass a greater value like 25 to sigmoid the output will be close to 1. The same would happen with a very small value which would result in threshold closer to 0.

> You should use a softmax function at the output layer if you are using ReLU in the hidden layers. Softmax converts the logits to class probabilities.

And also, with softmax, you would use categorical classes and not binary. You will have 2 classes and hence 2 output nodes.

Comment: ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_5 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (2,).

I changed the ``class_mode`` to categorical and got that error